# tutorial links for beginner in gear watch applications using Tizen OS

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

Please suggest some good tutorial links for beginner in gear watch applications using Tizen OS?

Comment: Check the answer please.

Answer (score 2):

You can develop Tizen App in *two* ways.

First one is using HTML,JS,CSS which **Tizen Web App**.A wearable Web application is basically a Web site stored on a wearable device. You can create it using Web-native languages, such as HTML5, CSS, and JavaScript.
Tizen Web app tutorial [link](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/getting-started/web-application/creating-your-first-tizen-wearable-web-application?langredirect=1).

And another one is using C which is called **Tizen Native App**. A wearable native application is created using the C language, and can be run on Tizen wearable devices. The application uses the native API, which provides various interfaces to the device hardware allowing you to take advantage of numerous capabilities tailored to run with limited device resources.
Tizen Native app tutorial [link](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/getting-started/native-application/creating-your-first-tizen-wearable-native-application?langredirect=1).

For developing Tizen App you have to install **Tizen Studio**. Get the Tizen Studio installation guide from [here](https://developer.tizen.org/sites/default/files/documentation/1_tizen_studio_windows.pdf).

Another useful [link](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/community/tip-tech/developing-tizen-apps-tizen-studio).

And one think i am not sure if you are looking for [Gear Watch Face Application](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/tutorials/web-application/w3chtml5supplementary-features/watch-application?langredirect=1) development guide.